# Why logarithmic density of sets are studied?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, analytic-number-theory

Natural density of a subset $S $ of positive integers  is defined  as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k\in S, k\le n}1 $$ whenever it exists.
The logarithmic density of $S$ is defined as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\log n}\sum\limits_{k\in S, k\le n}\frac{1}{k} $$
if it exists.

It is known that even though the natural density does not exist, logarithmic density does. So, my question is why the logarithmic density is studied and what is its importance?

Comment: The logarithmic density doesn't have to exist. Given your knowledge of Dirichlet series with a pole at $1$ isn't it obvious why both are interesting (together with the $\lim \sup$ which always exists) ?

Comment: I am not sure because it is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n \in S} n^{-s} = \sum_n (\sum_{k \in S, k \le n} 1/k) (n^{1-s}-(n+1)^{1-s})$$ If $$\sum_{k \in S, k \le n} 1/k = (C+o(1))\sum_{k \le n} 1/k$$ then as $s \to 1^+$  $$\sum_{n \in S} n^{-s} = \sum_n ((C+o(1))\sum_{k \le n} 1/k)(n^{1-s}-(n+1)^{1-s})= (C+o(1)) \zeta(s)$$

Comment: Okay, but why people check the log. density of a set $S$? What is the importance of saying that for example $0.2 + C < logdens(S) < 0.3 + \epsilon$?

Comment: @Ninja Anything whose existence is non trivial is (a) interesting and (b) probably going to be useful at some point to something else